# HDMI to HDMI monitor keeps going black every 10 seconds then comming back

Tags: hdmi, video

So i have my Pi connected to a small 7" monitor (feelworld T7 plus), and when i turn on the pi and let the video run it will periodically go black for just a second before coming back. The interval of the screen going black changes when i do some change in the config.txt. I have for example tried to change
#config_hdmi_boost to a higher number, but it has been most stable at 4, otherwise the black screen hasbeen even more frequent. I have also tried to switch between 3 different HDMI cables without any luck. When i change screen to my TV it works without any problem. I also just realized that it works when i run the Pi without any SD-card in it, so it just the text-terminal looking for anyting to run, which leds me to belive there is something with the configuration with the SD-card in ralation to the specfic monitor. The monitor works without any problem when i use hdmi signal from an other computer.

My config textfile looks lik e this at the moment:

```
# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=2
#hdmi_mode=38

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

#dispmanx_offline=1
```

Comment: What Pi? What OS? Try writing in paragraphs.

Comment: `tried to change #config_hdmi_boost` did you remove the `#`?